# Promise.all not waiting for the array of promises to resolve using Firebase database

Tags: firebase, promise, es6-promise

This question is not duplicate as i have already spent too much time in searching and applying the solutions which are already on stackoverflow. I am using the firebase database. In which i have two nodes one which has the users information and second which has all the comments on a post from users. I am fetching the comments and then again doing a request to the Firebase with respect to each comment for fetching the user information who has commented on the post. I am using promises for the requests in which i am fetching the user info from Firebase and for each request i am returning a new promise and pushing it to an array. Here is my code in which i am pushing the promises to array:

```
function getFirebaseComments() {
    $(".all_firebase_keys").each(function () {
        if (!allFirebaseKeys.includes($(this).val())) {
            allFirebaseKeys.push($(this).val());
            commentsRef.child($(this).val()).orderByKey().limitToLast(4).on("child_added", function (snap) {
                lists.push(getUser(snap.val().from_key, snap.val().comment, snap.ref.parent.key, snap.key));
            });
        }
    });
    Promise.all(lists).then(function (ful) {
        console.log(ful);
    });
}
```

This is the code in which i am returning the promises:

```
function getUser(id, comment, parentKey, commentKey) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        users = usersRef.child(id);
        users.once("value", function (snapshot) {
            $("#" + parentKey).append('<p id="' + commentKey + '">' + snapshot.val().first_name + " " + comment + '</p>');
            resolve({
                'parentKey': parentKey,
                'commentKey': commentKey,
                'first_name': snapshot.val().first_name,
                'comment': comment
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**Issue:**
The issue is that `Promise.all` is not waiting for all the promises to get resolved and execute as soon as the page is loaded. When the page is completely loaded and then i execute the following code in the console then it perfectly shows the results which i need:

```
Promise.all(lists).then(function (ful) {
    console.log(ful);
});
```

Please help how can i fix this issue.

Comment: `lists.push` is done in an asynchronous callback - therefore lists is empty at Promise.all(lists(

Comment: ... and so it is a duplicate.